# CameraX is not showing preview in Service

Tags: android, service, camera

I'm trying to preview camerx in my service. My service class extends LifecycleService() as camera x requires lifecycleOwner. My xml layout is as below

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</FrameLayout>
```

I have added permisions in manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and also granted runtime permissions

and this this is the way I'm trying to preview camerx in my service

```
private fun initCameraView() {
        try {
            mCameraLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_camera_view, null)
            cameraPreview = mCameraLayout?.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview)
            paramCam!!.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END
            paramCam!!.x = 0
            paramCam!!.y = 0
            mWindowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
            mWindowManager!!.addView(mCameraLayout, paramCam)
            val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)

            cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
                // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
                val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
                cameraPreview!!.implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
                // Preview
                val preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setSurfaceProvider(cameraPreview!!.surfaceProvider)
                    }


                // Select back camera as a default
                val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA

                try {
                    // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                    // Bind use cases to camera
                    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this, cameraSelector, preview
                    )

                } catch (exc: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
                }

            }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
        } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

but my camera preview is always black.It doesn't shows preview

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem as you. After much searching, I finally found the solution is custom LifeCycleOwner:

```
class LifeCycleOwner : LifecycleOwner {

    private val lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)

    init {
        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.CREATED
    }

    fun start() {
        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
    }

    fun stop() {
        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED
    }

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle = lifecycleRegistry
}
```

Then you can start camera like this:

```
private val lifeCycleOwner = LifeCycleOwner()

fun startCamera(){
    ...
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
         lifeCycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview
    )
    lifeCycleOwner.start()
    ...
```